# SwiftUI place around center object

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout, swiftui-zstack

Say the blue rectangle is in the center of the red rectangle, and the green needed to be on top and the yellow on the left.

How would one do this in SwiftUI with alignment guides? None of the sizes are known, but the yellow and blue height match, and green and blue width match.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63165931/12299030?

Comment: Hey Asperi, thanks for taking your time. It does not answer my question, as the big rectangle aint in the center of the parent view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from https://swiftui-lab.com on twitter

With my helper method:

```
extension View {
    func overlay<Overlay: View>(alignment: Alignment, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Overlay) -> some View {
        overlay(builder(), alignment: alignment)
    }
}
```

it can be done so:

```
Color.red
  .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
      Color.clear.frame(width: 0)
      Color.yellow
      .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0.height + 10 }
    }
  }
  .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
      Color.clear.frame(height: 0)
      Color.blue
        .alignmentGuide(.leading) { $0.width + 10 }
    }
  }
  .padding(100) // padding given for the example
```